# How can i install Google Chrome to use with protractor during automation CI run

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, continuous-integration, dependencies, teamcity

My organization doesn't have Google Chrome natively installed within the Virtual Machines configured for automation CI and it's not allowed to install Chrome globally on those machines.

We are using protractor for automation of angular apps which goes really well with Google Chrome.

Is it possible to install Google Chrome at runtime for execution locally so that we can have smooth execution on those VM's. If yes what and how can i install chrome.

We are using TeamCity for CI/CD. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Update 29/12/2019: A suggestion, you containerize your app. Which means you need to include the step of chrome installation on when the image in being built on your VM.
Generally such a step is included in the Dockerfile. 
more info on how to write Dockerfile: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

Within your angular app, to handle any browser's binary installation, I include it in `package.json` inside the `scripts` section:

```
"webdriver-update": "./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --standalone --versions.standalone=3.8.0 --chrome --versions.chrome=76.0.3809.68",
```

This has worked for me in maintaining the dependency on the chrome versions.